# 「卒業して以来」と「卒業した以来」どちらが正しいですか？

Tags: grammar, tense

I got the wrong answer when playing the 'JLPT Taisen' japanese game.
The question is: "田中さんとは、学校を_____以来、会っていない".
I think the answer is "卒業した", but "卒業して" is correct.

Please teach me why?

[image: JLPT Taisen question]

Comment: A very concise answer would probably be that 以来 is an adverb and that an adverb can't be modified by a sub-clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「~て以来」 is a set phrase. You just use it like that. It means "since + (an action described by a verbal sentence)".
[https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-ていらい-te-irai/](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n2-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%89%E3%81%84-te-irai/)

「~た以来」does not have any sense. It is not possible to precede 以来  with a verb in the ~た form.

Comment: 1. That's indeed what can be called a set phrase but that does not explain *why* た以来 is wrong. 2. We prefer real answers rather than link answers. So that even if the links die the information is still here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added explanations.